# Added projects in Global.json does not reflect in Solution Explorer

Tags: visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-1.0

I followed below steps to include MVC source code from GitHub

1. Cloned MVC project from GitHub
2. Created sample MVC core app using VS 2015 IDE
3. Open Global.json file, added entry `"projects": [ "src", "test", "D://Mvcsrc//src" ]`
4. The projects in cloned repo should open all projects in solution explorer as per Global.json functionality

But nothing gets opened in solution explorer. I am using RC1-update1

Comment: how about "D:\\Mvcsrc\\src"?

Comment: Tried that too already..

Comment: Correct path would be `"D:/Mvcsrc/src"`. Which version of MVC you try to use? The RC1 or the latest from GitHub?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you to verify, **which version of MVC you downloaded**. If you prefer to clone MVC repository, then you should reset the head of the repository to RC1 (by using `git checkout 6.0.0-rc1` for example) to work with RC1 sources. You can go to [Release](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/releases) or [Tags](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/tags) part of the GitHub repository and download `6.0.0-rc1` source directly. After that you can unzip `Mvc-6.0.0-rc1.zip` in some directory, like `D:\Mvc-6.0.0-rc1` for example, and add either add `"C:\\Mvc-6.0.0-rc1\\src"` or `"C:/Mvc-6.0.0-rc1/src"`. The project files should be added directly after you save the changes (by <kbd>Ctrl-S</kbd> for example) in `global.json`.

Comment: Thanks !! Its working ... I just cloned and it took from DEV branch, RC1 and Dev branch code are different.